# How to keep track of updated fields of an RDD in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

There is an issue that i am dealing with on keeping track of updated fields in spark RDD.
assume that we have an RDD like this:

```
(1,2)
(2,10)
(5,9)
(3,8)
(8,15)
```

based on some conditions value of some `keys` may change. for example the value of `key=2` changes from 10 to 11. then the value of a key in RDD that its value is equal to the key of updated row should be changed respectively. for example `key=1` has value equal to 2, which 2 is a key in other row. because value of key=2 changes to 11. then the value of key=1 should change to 11 to. after some execution RDD looks like this:

```
(1,11)
(2,11)
(5,9)
(3,7)
(8,7)
```

is there any efficient way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about a DStream (of RDDs). In that case you can use the `updateStateByKey` method.

To use `updateStateByKey`, you need to provide a function `update(events, oldState)` that takes in the events that arrived for a key and its previous state, and returns a newState to store for it.

- **events**: is a list of events that arrived in the current batch (may be empty).
- **oldState**: is an optional state opbject, stored withing an `Option`; it might be missing if there was no prevous state for the key.
- **newState**: returned by the function, is also an `Option`.

The result of `updateStateByKey()` will be a new `DStream` that contains an RDD of (key, state) pairs.

Basic Example:

```scala
def myUpdate(values: Seq[Long], state: Option[Long]) = {
  // select new value
}

myDStream.updateStateByKey(myUpdate _)
```

Background given from the book "Learning Spark" (O'Reilly).

Comment: first thank you for your reply. i am working on GraphX and my problem is about updating nodes label. each key represents a community label, and i want to merge them, for example community 1 and 2 merges with 3. and then 3 merges with 4. i want to inform  or update the communities 1 and 2 to get the community 4 label, not 3. is there any way to perform this?